# GAE Datastore saves only parts of the object

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have an object called AdUser that looks like this:

```
@PersistenceCapable
public class AdUser{

@Persistent
protected final int _id;

@Persistent
protected String _firstName, _lastName;

@Persistent
protected double _bankRoll;

@Persistent(serialized = "true", embeddedElement = "true", defaultFetchGroup = "true") 
protected final User _googleUser;

@PrimaryKey
@Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
private Key key;
```

Then, in my code I create a new AdUser object and fill it with data. the User class for the _googleUser datamember is taken from com.google.appengine.api.users.User

Then In my code I run the following commands:

```
try {
        pm.makePersistent(user);
    } finally {
       pm.close();
}
```

and afterwards:

```
PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
Query q = pm.newQuery(AdUser.class);
try {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<AdUser> list = (List<AdUser>) q.execute();
    userArray = new ArrayList<AdUser>(list);
} finally {
    q.closeAll();
    pm.close();
}
```

When I iterate over the list I see that for example the _firstName and _lastName datamembers are retrieved correctly, but for example the _id field and _googleUser field are not, and return as 0 and null respectively.

I am pretty clueless here. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set as `final` the `_id` and the `_googleUser` and you have not initialized them. Thus, their value cannot be modified when you are creating instances of the class and the persist them in the datastore.

Comment: I have initialized them in the constructor.
When I use the debugger I can see that on the `pm.makePersistent(user);` call those values are set.

Comment: Hmm, seems strange. If you remove the `final` from these two, does it change anything?

Comment: Yes.
I think I know why.
Probably when the datastore retrieves an object in order to place it in an object, it creates a new object with the default constructor, then fills it up. In that case, It can't fill those final fields after creation, and the remain null/0.